tables do not refresh or display properly when using ui.splitter with python NiceGUI
I am trying to create a web page which has two panes. Left one has some data which when selected, I need to refresh data in the right pane. Left pane is a table with selectable values and right pane is only for display.
Problems:

I get the panes to split but the table in the right pane is not left justified and there is a large blank space between the left table and right table.
I cannot select the values in the left table through I can see the selection box
For some reason the connection keeps dropping.

My code below:
...
from nicegui import ui
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy

tblname = 'xxxx'
datadf = pd.DataFrame()

def table_selected(e):
    
    global tblname
    global datadf

    tblname = e.selection[0]['Sites']
    ui.notify(tblname + ' selected')
    engine_remote = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://xxx:xxx@localhost:3306/xxx')
    sqlquery = 'select * from ' + tblname + ' order by TIMESTAMP desc limit 100'
    datadf = pd.read_sql(sqlquery, con=engine_remote)


def main() -> None:

    global datadf

    engine_remote = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://xxx:xxx@localhost:3306/xxx')
    sqlquery = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) < `UPDATE_TIME`"
    df = pd.read_sql(sqlquery, con=engine_remote)
    df.columns = ['Sites']
    sqlquery = 'select * from ' + tblname + ' order by TIMESTAMP desc limit 100'
    datadf = pd.read_sql(sqlquery, con=engine_remote)

    with ui.splitter(horizontal=False, reverse=False, value=70,on_change=lambda e: ui.notify(e.value)) as splitter:
        with splitter.before:
            table = ui.table(title = 'Monitored Sites', columns=[{'name': col, 'label': col, 'field': col} for col in df.columns], rows=df.to_dict('records'),
                 row_key='Sites', pagination=10, selection='single', on_select=table_selected)
        with splitter.after:
    #       ui.label('Select table to see data').classes('ml-2')
            table = ui.table(title = tblname, columns=[{'name': col, 'label': col, 'field': col} for col in datadf.columns], rows=datadf.to_dict('records'),
                 pagination=10)

    ui.notify('my notification')

if __name__ in ('__main__', '__mp_main__'):
    main()
    ui.run(on_air=True, port=80, storage_secret='nicegui-secret')

...
